# Scrape a table data from a paginated webpage where the url does not change but the table data changes

Tags: json, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

website: nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered-products

The code below runs but takes 7 hours to render 200 pages out of 5802, I'd appreciate it if anybody can help me find how to scape this website faster

```
# pip install webdriver-manager --user
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, 
StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered- 
 products/')

container2 = []

wait_time_out = 20

ignored_exceptions 
=NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)


for _ in range(0, 5802+1):
    rows = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_out, 
ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
        ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//* 
[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr')))

    for row in rows:
        time.sleep(10)
        container2.append([table_data.text for table_data in 
        row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')])
        WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_out, 
        ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* 
           [@id="table_1_next"]'))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: don't post pics of your code. post the actual code

Comment: also what's the url/site? you haven't really given us much to work with here.

Comment: the website is https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered-products/

Comment: for _ in range(0, 5802+1):
    rows = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_out, ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)).until(
        ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr')))
    for row in rows:
        time.sleep(10)
        container2.append([table_data.text for table_data in row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')])
    WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_out, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table_1_next"]'))).click()
    time.sleep(10)

Comment: This scrapes the tables by row and appends it to a list (container), please i really need a way to do it faster, even if i have to use a different tool

Comment: put the code up in the original post (edit it), not in  the comments. What you want to do when asking a question in SO is provide as much data and code needed to reproduce your error. Essentially, we want to be able to copy and paste your code and debug. This will help us explain to you what's wrong and what needs to be fixed in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is retrieved through ajax call. Just get the data directly from the source. This got me all the data in about 50 seconds:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get _wp_http_referer
url = 'https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered-products/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
wdtNonce = soup.find_all('input', {'type':'hidden'})[0]['value']  



# URL to ajax
url = 'https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=1'

# Headers for the request
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

# form data needed to query in the post
payload = {
'draw': '1',
'columns[0][data]': '0',
'columns[0][name]': 'ID',
'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[0][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[0][search][value]': '',
'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[1][data]': '1',
'columns[1][name]': 'product_group',
'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[1][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[1][search][value]': '',
'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[2][data]': '2',
'columns[2][name]': 'product_name',
'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[2][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[2][search][value]': '',
'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[3][data]': '3',
'columns[3][name]': 'presentation',
'columns[3][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[3][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[3][search][value]': '',
'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[4][data]': '4',
'columns[4][name]': 'active_ingredent',
'columns[4][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[4][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[4][search][value]': '',
'columns[4][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[5][data]': '5',
'columns[5][name]': 'applicant_name',
'columns[5][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[5][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[5][search][value]': '',
'columns[5][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[6][data]': '6',
'columns[6][name]': 'country',
'columns[6][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[6][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[6][search][value]': '',
'columns[6][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[7][data]': '7',
'columns[7][name]': 'manufacturer',
'columns[7][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[7][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[7][search][value]': '',
'columns[7][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[8][data]': '8',
'columns[8][name]': 'date_approved',
'columns[8][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[8][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[8][search][value]': '',
'columns[8][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[9][data]': '9',
'columns[9][name]': 'expiry_date',
'columns[9][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[9][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[9][search][value]': '',
'columns[9][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[10][data]': '10',
'columns[10][name]': 'registration_number',
'columns[10][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[10][orderable]': 'true',
'columns[10][search][value]': '',
'columns[10][search][regex]': 'false',
'order[0][column]': '0',
'order[0][dir]': 'asc',
'start': '0',
'length': '10000',
'search[value]': '',
'search[regex]': 'false',
'wdtNonce': wdtNonce}


# Iterating through the form data above to pull out column names
cols = []
for k, v in payload.items():
    if 'name' in k:
        cols.append(v)

# initialize a list of rows
rows = []
start = 0
while True:
    
    # Update the start value of the form data to go through the "pages"
    payload.update({'start':str(start)})
    
    # Retunr the json fronm the post ajax
    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    
    # Add the list of data into the list of "rows"
    rows += jsonData['data']
    
    print('Gathered rows: %d - %d' %(start+1, start+len(jsonData['data'])))
    
    # If the data is less than 10000 items, we know we are on the last "page"
    # So we'll break the loop 
    if len(jsonData['data']) < 10000:
        print('Done!')
        break
        
    # Update the start variable so that on the next loop, it
    # updates the start parameter in the form data to then get the
    # next "page"
    start = len(rows)

# Create the table from the final list of rows
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
           ID product_group  ... expiry_date registration_number
0           1                ...  30/10/2022             03-0740
1           3   ANIMAL FEED  ...  30/07/2023             A9-0735
2           4   ANIMAL FEED  ...  30/07/2023             A9-0744
3           5   ANIMAL FEED  ...  27/06/2023             A9-0721
4           6   ANIMAL FEED  ...  27/06/2023             A9-0722
      ...           ...  ...         ...                 ...
58011  58.013                ...                          Apr-65
58012  58.014                ...                         A4-2582
58013  58.015                ...                         A4-0851
58014  58.016                ...                         A4-6613
58015  58.017                ...                         A4-3601

[58016 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you @chitown88. I ran this code and got the following error

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Can you please add comments to your code so it is easier to understand? I have really never seen this before. Thank you

Comment: comments are added in there. The error means it's not returning the json to you. Does it get through an of the data? Ie do you get print statement output of `'Gathered rows: 1 - 10000'` ?

Comment: No it doesn't return any rows

Comment: @UyiosaAkpasubi, I added one little part at the beginning. Can you try it again?

Comment: It worked, I have successfully retrieved all the records. Thank you very much