Scraping Paginated Table with same url
I am trying to scrape the paginated table from "https://tariffs.ib-net.org/sites/IBNET/TariffTable#" where url remains same for all pages.
I have already referred to below pages for help, but couldn't reach to a solution -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180819/scrape-a-table-data-from-a-paginated-webpage-where-the-url-does-not-change-but-t
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635015/using-selenium-to-scrape-a-table-across-multiple-pages-when-the-url-doesnt-chan
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73362475/using-selenium-to-scrape-paginated-table-data-python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75479097/scrape-multiple-pages-with-the-same-url-using-python-selenium
It was interesting to know from here "Scraping dynamic DataTable of many pages but same URL" that we can extract the json file but I have no clue how to do that.
Any help will be greatly appreciated,
My trials:
Code 1:
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
#from .actions.wheel_input import ScrollOrigin
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import urllib
import requests

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://tariffs.ib-net.org/sites/IBNET/TariffTable#'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
x=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="datatab_length"]/label/select')
drop=Select(x)

drop.select_by_visible_text("100")
time.sleep(10)

table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline collapsed']")))

#utility=[]
#city=[]
#service=[]
#date=[]
#fifteenm3=[]
#fiftym3 = []
#hundredm3 = []
data_list=[]
while True:
    # Extract data from the current page
    rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline collapsed']//tbody")
    
    for row in rows:
        columns = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        data_list.append([col.text.strip() for col in columns])
        print(data_list)
        next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='paginate_button next']/a")
        if next_button:
             # Click the next page button
            next_button.click()
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
        else:
            break 

Code 2:
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import urllib
import requests


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
actions=ActionChains(browser)
browser.get("https://tariffs.ib-net.org/sites/IBNET/TariffTable#")
time.sleep(5)

table_header= browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[@id='datatab']/thead")
header_row = []
for header in table_header:
    header_row.append(header.text)
#print(header_row)

utility=[]
city=[]
service=[]
date=[]
fifteenm3=[]
fiftym3=[]
hundredm3=[]

while True:
    all_rows = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='row']//tbody")
    for index in range(len(all_rows)):
        all_columns = all_rows[index].find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@role='row']")
        utility.append(all_columns[0].text)
        print(utility)
        city.append(all_columns[1].text)
        print(city)
        service.append(all_columns[2].text)
        print(service)
        date.append(all_columns[3].text)
        print(date)
        fifteenm3.append(all_columns[4].text)
        print(fifteenm3)
        fiftym3.append(all_columns[5].text)
        print(fiftym3)
        hundredm3.append(all_columns[6].text)
        print(hundredm3)
    if browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='paginate_button next']/a"):
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='paginate_button next']/a").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
    else:
        break
        
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Utlity']=utility
df['service']=service
df['city']=city
df['date']=date
df['15m3']=fifteenm3
df['50m3']=fiftym3
df['100m3']=hundredm3

df.to_csv('data.csv')


The codes above either runs for few pages & then gets timed out, even after making the code sleep for a while in between or keeps on looping the same page after running properly for a while.

The answer mentioned on Scraping dynamic DataTable of many pages but same URL is applicable here. On a high level, to get the accurate URL and values, here is what you want to do:

Head over to the network tab in developer console. Clear all current logs.
Click on the next page of the table on the webpage and spot the request sent by the browser in the network tab.
Right click on the request and copy the request as fetch or curl (whatever you prefer).
Now that you have the request along with its header information, head over to your code, and paste the request (you will have to convert the request to use the libraries available in your language ofcourse).
Change the parameters of the request to get desired behavior. In this case, if the parameter length is big enough, you should get all the data. If that is too slow, or unreliable, you can get the entries in batches of 100s while retrying the pages that lead to dropped requests.

Here is the python code for the request from my browser: https://pym.dev/p/2ueeq/. You can simplify this because a lot of this information is not required to be sent.
I am not familiar with your level of expertise with dev tools, so if you are stuck at any/all the steps here, lets discuss this in comments under this answer.

Did you, by any chance, generate this answer with ChatGPT or another AI? It looks very much so.

@Shraiysh - Thank you so much for your help. It work till few pages & then gives below error. I tried reducing the len to 99 & also tried increasing it to 1000, but it stops after few pages.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[78], line 117
    115     else:
    116         print(f"Success for start = {start}")
--> 117     all_entries.append((response.json()['data']))
    119 print(len(all_entries)) 

KeyError: 'data'



No @BarrythePlatipus - it was all me. I don’t know how to prove that I most definitely am, not a robot and have not used any AI for writing this :)

@r_sh_07 after how many pages, precisely? If you are somewhat familiar with coding in python, you should be able to debug this - it seems that the response at whatever iteration this gets stuck at - the response does not have the data. You probably need to log the json and check why.

There is actually no data beyond 16000 something records, so it's all good,
Thank you so much for the help @Shraiysh
